# Python: How do I detect visible shape detection in Tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, collision-detection

I am new to Python and I have a program that has 2 classes, one is essentially a rectangle and the other is essentially a circle. I am drawing them using the `Canvas` in `Tkinter` in the way below:

```
def draw(self):
    self.canvas.delete("all")
    self.rect.draw(self.canvas)
    self.ball.draw(self.canvas)
```

The `Ball` class has its location variables and diameter variables and the `Rect` class has its location and dimension variables.

I am wondering how I detect the collision between these two "shapes". I know that one was is to treat the `Ball` as a square and do basic rectangle collision but I would like to know how to be precise.

I was also wondering if there was anything similar in Python to the way shape collision can be done in Java. In my Java game I use the following code to detect collision between any 2 `Shape`s:

```
public boolean collisionCheck(Shape a, Shape b) {
     Area aA = new Area(a);
     Area aB = new Area(b);
     aA.intersect(aB);
     return !aA.isEmpty();
}
```

Is there anything similar to this simple solution in Python?
And if not how would I go about circle-rectangle collision in Python?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure this out using a method that `Tkinter`'s `Canvas` object has. Every time something is drawn using `Canvas` it is given an ID. So as long as you record that ID somewhere you can use the `find_overlapping` method that the `Canvas` object has.

Say you have an object, in my case a custom `Platform` object, that keeps the ID stored in a variable. I did so like this:

```
def draw_platform(self, canvas): #Located in the Platform Class
    self.ID = canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x+self.w, self.y+self.h)
```

Now I can use this ID to determine if there are any object overlapping it.

```
def check_collision(self, plat, other_plat):
    result = self.canvas.find_overlapping(plat.x, plat.y, plat.x + plat.w, plat.y + plat.h)
    for i in result:
        if i == other_plat.ID:
            return True
   return False
```

`result` returns a tuple of the ID's that are located within the rectangle bounds entered into `find_overlapping`. You can than loop through the tuple to see if any of the ID's match your other shape.

This works great for Rectangle-Rectangle collision and Circle-Rectangle collision.